Adding a prefix command to all ctest executions
I am following the instructions to use the mutation testing framework Mull and integrating it with CMake
https://mull.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/CMakeIntegration.html
The last step involves executing the test using the mull-runner.
For example:
$ mull-runner-12 test/my_test.exe
I have many tests in my project, and I simply usually run all of them with ctest.
Is there a way to tell ctest, from the command, to add a prefix to all execution commands? (in this case the prefix will be mull-runner-12).

From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html#command:add_test :

Added in version 3.29: The target's TEST_LAUNCHER, if set, will be used to launch the command:
<launcher> <command>


From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TEST_LAUNCHER.html#prop_tgt:TEST_LAUNCHER :

This property is initialized by the value of the CMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER ...

Do make -DCMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER=mull-runner-12.

The other way for previous version of cmake was to overwrite cmake commands, like so:
function(add_test NAME name COMMAND command)
   _add_test(${NAME} ${name} ${COMMAND} mull-runner-12 ${command} ${ARGV})
endfunction()

Add such function on top of your CMakeLists.txt or somewhere.

Ah, pretty recent option. So, this can be only to be set at cmake-time not at ctest-time?

pretty recent option there are ways for previous versions this can be only to be set at cmake-time not at ctest-time? yes

Is this how the variable is used: cmake ... -DCMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER="mull-runner-11;--strict;--ld-search-path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ? If so I am not seeing a difference in the executed command: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/jobs/8455957522#L833

check your cmake --version

3.30.0-rc4 https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/jobs/8456996895#L421

Added the second idea. No idea then.
